# Angular2 service: Getting different instances in two components even though there's only one provider

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

In my angular2 app, I have several modules, most beyond the root module are being lazy loaded

```
Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  ...
  {
    path: 'item',
    loadChildren: 'app/item/item.module#ItemModule'
  }
```

In the ItemModule, I have an ItemSearchService listed under "providers"

```
@NgModule({
imports:      [ 
...
],
declarations: [ 
  ItemDetailComponent,
  ItemComponent,
  ItemSearchComponent
],
exports:      [ 
],
providers:    [ 
  ItemSearchService
]
})
```

So from what I understand of the module structure, both ItemDetailComponent and ItemSearchComponent should get the same instance of ItemSearchService when it's injected in the constructor.

```
export class ItemSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: Http, private itemSearch: ItemSearchService ... )

export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private itemSearch: ItemSearchService ...)
```

Yet when I run this, as soon as I navigate from IteamSearchComponent to ItemDetailComponent, ItemDetailComponent gets a new, separate instance of the ItemSearchService, which is of course not intended.

It all works fine when I provide the ItemSearchService in the root module, then all the Components get the same instance, but when I move the provider to the ItemModule, something seems to go wrong.

Could this have anything to do with the ItemModule being lazy loaded? I'm at a bit of a loss here, it's not a huge problem right now since I can just provide the service as an app-wide singleton in the AppModule, but I don't want to have all my services live in the root module in the long run, so am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 there is [Hierarchical Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html).

Every component has it's own injector and injector tree filled with parent injectors. You can read more about it in the link provided.

If you place a debug on the ctor of the service you will find that the ctor is called twice. Once per component.